# How to get year difference between two NSDates with multiple decimal digits

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `NSTimeInterval` calculated from two `NSDate` objects. How do I return the year value of this interval as a `double` or `CGFloat` with multiple decimal digits?

Let's say, I have someone's dob and I wanna return his age as a decimal like xx.xxxxxxxx years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use NSCalendar. And make the difference with the NSDate objects. Here is an example:

```
// The time interval 
NSTimeInterval theTimeInterval = ...;

// Get the system calendar
NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

// Create the NSDates
NSDate *date1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDate *date2 = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:theTimeInterval sinceDate:date1]; 

// Get conversion to months, days, hours, minutes
NSCalendarUnit unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;

NSDateComponents *breakdownInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date1  toDate:date2  options:0];
NSLog(@"Break down: %i min : %i hours : %i days : %i months", [breakdownInfo minute], [breakdownInfo hour], [breakdownInfo day], [breakdownInfo month]);
```

Comment: This doesn't return the year value.

Comment: Just calculate the number of years from the breakdown values of months, should be a piece of cake ;) Specially since the `NSYearCalendarUnit` was deprecated. Alternatively you could use `NSCalendarUnitYear`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `NSTimeInterval` specifies the number of seconds, all you need to do to get an approximation<sup>*</sup> is dividing by the number of seconds in a year:

```
#define SEC_PER_YEAR (365*24*60*60)
...
NSTimeInterval diff = ...
double diffYear = ((double)diff)/SEC_PER_YEAR;
```

<sup>*</sup> This number would not be exact, because the number of seconds per year changes depending on the year.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only the time interval, it's too late. 365.5 days are usually more than a year, but sometimes they are not. You can't tell from the time interval.

Dates are complicated. Tell us *exactly* what you want.

Comment: closer to 365.25, there is in general a leap year every four years this .25 instead of .5.

Comment: Let's say, I have someone's dob and I wanna return his age as a decimal like xx.xxxxxxxx years old.